# JBOSS EAP 6.4 run as service does not pick the correct JAVA

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have installed JBOSS EAP6.4 on a RHEL box and during the installation it has created default service. I am trying to start the service root user `service jbossas start` through and it fails with following message: **/usr/share/jbossas/bin/standalone.sh: line 306: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory**

However server starts perfects fine when it is standard through `/usr/share/jbossas/bin/standalone.sh`

As I understand, jboss user underwhich service would be running somehow picking up the incorrect java path - again default path.

I could be wrong here, as such how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable for the user's profile in the OS level.

Another way to do this, but you should avoid that, is to set JAVA_HOME environment variable through the `/etc/init.d/jbossas` service script file of EAP 6 (installed as RPM installation). Such variables should be set through `/etc/jbossas/jbossas.conf` file which is used internally by the service script of the installation.